# How casting of array address are coming differently in C

Tags: c, pointers

After long time, I was doing some experiments on array with this program and printing output in decimal using %lu.

The confusing part I observed is when I use cast with unsigned long, array address '&thing+1' increment by just +1,

```
140733866717248 140733866717248
140733866717249 140733866717249
```

When I don't cast then array addresses,

```
140720750924480 140720750924480
140720750924481 140720750924488
```

How address in first part increment by just 1 on int type address '&'?

How casting affect the values here?

Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
#if 0 /* (unsigned long)&thing --> 140733866717248
         (unsigned long)&thing+1 --> 140733866717249*/
{
        int thing[8];
        printf("%lu %lu\n", (unsigned long)thing, (unsigned long)&thing );
        printf("%lu %lu\n", (unsigned long)thing+1, (unsigned long)&thing+1);
        return 0;
}
#endif
#if 1 /* &thing --> 140720750924480
         &thing+1 --> 140720750924488*/
{
        int thing[8];
        printf("%lu %lu\n", thing, &thing );
        printf("%lu %lu\n", thing+1, &thing+1);
        return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `(type)object+value` parses as `((type)object)+value` not `(type)(object+value)`

Comment: Adding 1 to an integer type adds 1. Adding 1 to a pointer type adds the size of the object type.

Comment: mrigendra, Avoid undefined behavior attempting to print an address with `"%lu"`.  Use `"%p"` to print a `void *`.  `printf("%lu %lu\n", thing, &thing );` --> `printf("%p %p\n", (void *) thing, (void *) &thing );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you are adding 1 to unsigned long values, so that just adds 1

In the second example, you are adding 1 to a pointer, which increases the pointer value by the size of the pointed at type.  So with `thing + 1`, `thing` is an `int *`, so it increases by sizeof(int), while with `&thing +1`, `&thing` is an `int (*)[8]`, so it increases by the size of that (32).

Result from running the code you posted:

```
140733007047872 140733007047872
140733007047876 140733007047904
```

Comment: hmm, this happened because I was too preoccupied trying to print in decimal, I forgot about operator precedence. Facepalm for me.